# Sealing interface with generics in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ecj, java-15, java-sealed-type

The following is legal (i.e. I can compile it) and works in Java 15 with preview features enabled (in eclipse 2020-09)

```
public sealed interface Quantity<T> permits QuantityImpl { }
public record QuantityImpl<T extends Number>(T value) implements Quantity<T> { }

public class Play {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Quantity<Float> q = new QuantityImpl<>(3.0f);
        System.out.println(q instanceof Quantity);
    }
}
```

However, eclipse is complaining in `Quantity.java` at `... permits QuantityImpl`. When hovering over `QuantityImpl` one can read:

```
Permitted type QuantityImpl does not declare Quantity<T> as direct super interface
```

Is this, even though it compiles, a valid complaint or a bug in eclipse?

Comment: Could the warning refer to the raw type `Quantity` used in `q instance Quantity`?

Comment: Complaining *where specifically*?

Comment: The error shared actually contradicts, since the declaration `public record QuantityImpl<T extends Number>(T value) implements Quantity<T> { }` is valid. But what's with `QuantityMax1D` in your code?

Comment: @marstran I clarified, it is complaining in Quantity.java, not in Play.java.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Sorry, I clarified the question: when hovering over QuantityImpl in the `...permits QuantityImpl` clause in Quantity.java

Comment: @Naman `QuantityMax1D` was irrelevant, thanks, I removed it.

Comment: What happens if you use Lombok `@Value` to create your `QuantityImpl` instead of `record`?

Comment: This smells to me like an eclipse bug.  Have you tried it with `javac`?

Comment: @BrianGoetz yes, definitely. I can reproduce it with Eclipse. `javac` compiles this code without problems.